# how to enable udev rules in docker

Tags: docker, udev

I want to have `udev` rules to create devices in docker:

```
KERNEL=="xxx",SUBSYSTEM=="misc", GROUP="users", MODE="0660"
```

and then trigger it in docker, but the access for this node is still as below:

```
crw------- 1 root root
```

How can I change the permissions to reach the expected result below?

```
crw-rw---- 1 root users
```

Comment: You mean you change the udev, but when the device replug, it not change permissions?

Comment: yes I want this node to have 0660 access for group users, but only I put this udev file in host can make it work.

Comment: Have you restart udev service after you change?

Comment: And I think you have made udev as a volumn to container? Otherwise, container not know there is a device there.

Comment: #sudo service udev restart
 * udev does not support containers, not started

Comment: how to made udev as a volumn to container?  currently I run with                                 #docker run --it --privileged -v /dev:/dev myimage /bin/bash

Comment: I suggest you share a minimal `Dockerfile` which could reproduce your issue in your question, also the command how you start your container, them guys could know your base image, command, and other detail about your issue. This could help you get more help.

Comment: As a general rule Docker containers don't have access to hardware devices unless explicitly given and don't run daemons like udev; this seems like something that would better be run on a physical host.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider applying the udev rule on your **HOST machine** and then giving access to your container. This would look like

```
docker run -v /dev/node_name:/dev/node_name
```

with [docker CLI](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/), or

```
devices:
   - /dev/node_name:/dev/node_name
```

with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/).

If your device is already connected, make sure to run the rule before creating the container. No need to reboot your PC or restart udev daemon. Simply type `sudo udevadm trigger` (`udevtrigger` for some OS) and it should reload its rules ! =)